# MVC: Delay jquery script execution until after Layout script has completed

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm developing an ASP.net project that uses quite a bit of client side Jquery scripting.  In the layout.cshtml page I have an Ajax call which returns information about the logged in user.  All pages in my application depend on this information. I therefore need a mechanism so that I don't execute any script in my individual views until the call on the layout page has completed.

Generally I would use jquery deferreds but this is quite difficult as the calls are in 2 unconnected files (e.g. layout.cshtml and individual view cshtml).  The other options I can think of are to make the initial call synchronous which I don't want to do or have some sort of wait loop (e.g. setTimeout(checkVal, 200), neither solution appeals to me.

Below is a very simplistic sample of what I am trying to do.

Layout.cshtml

```
$(document).ready()
{
    function LoadUserData()
    {
        return $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                url: baseUrl + "/Account/GetUserMeta",
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#userMetaData").data('meta', res);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Sample View (Index.cshtml)

```
$(document).ready()
{
    function DoStuff()
    {
        //This may not be available yet
        var meta = $("#userMetaData").data('meta');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use initializer code within an ajax call and not directly in the controller (or a service that is called from a controller)?

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050559/first-jquery-ajax-call-collides-with-the-second) to show how to use a Promise. But why are making the ajax call as @A.BurakErbora has noted?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean.  The initializer code is common to all pages.  It returns a pretty complex dataset, if I wanted to return this server   side i would have to add it to all my controller calls. The application is heavy client side

Comment: No you don't, You can use `@Html.Action()` to call a controller method that returns the data you want

Comment: I did try to use @Html.Action initially however it caused by webpage to render as html text.  I returned a JsonResult from the Html.Action().  I could convert my data to a string and return a string then parse it as json on the client.

Comment: Actually the trick was to return a PartialViewResult and create an empty partial view with no markup. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would also suggest using a base controller class that you can extend all your controllers from, and have common functions there. You can then have either a base view model that hosts these properties or add them simply to the ViewBag.